# How to do math with coordinate labels in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-pic

I have a set of Ti*k*Z `pic`s defined as

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    shape/.pic = {
                   \node [draw] (xx) {};
                   \coordinate (-right) at (xx.east);
                   \coordinate (-left) at (xx.west);
                 }
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{
                            \pic at (\i*1cm,0) (n-\i) {shape};
                           }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Assume that I want to connect these `pic`s in order. For example, I want to connect `n-1-right` to `n-2-left` and `n-2-right` to `n-3-left` and so on. Can I do such a "plus 1" operation with labels? For example, I am looking for a code such as

```
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,9}{
                           \draw (n-\i-right) -- (n-\i+1-left);
                          }
```

Note that my problem is not connecting these `pic`s to each other (i.e., this particular example is **not** my problem), but doing math with labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count` option and do the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    shape/.pic = {
       \node [draw] (xx) {};
       \coordinate (-right) at (xx.east);
       \coordinate (-left) at (xx.west);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10} {
    \pic at (\i*1cm,0) (n-\i) {shape};
}

\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,...,9} {
    \draw (n-\i-right) -- (n-\j-left);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complicated calculations, you can use something like:

```
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,9} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i+1}
    \draw (n-\i-right) -- (n-\j-left);
}
```